# Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects in colab

Tags: huggingface-transformers, python-wheel, huggingface-tokenizers

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i am trying to clone a repository from github in colab. During setting the environment i got this error. i want to install transformer==2.5.1.

Comment: Please share the steps to reproduce the error. Why don't you install this version via pip?

Comment: I already tried to install through pip in colab